# python:split a list of strings into multiple lists before a certain value

Tags: python, string, list, split, python-itertools

I have a list as follows,

```
my_list = ['France, the weather is nice', 'the house is beautiful', 'we have a fresh start here','France, the dinner is amazing', 'the lady is lovely', 'France, the house is beautiful','the location is fascinating']
```

I want to split the list into multiple list every time the word 'France,' is in the string, so the output should be,

```
desired_list = [['France, the weather is nice', 'the house is beautiful', 'we have a fresh start here'],['France, the dinner is amazing', 'the lady is lovely'],['France, the house is beautiful','the location is fascinating']]
```

I have tried the following, but would like to keep the sentence that has 'France,' too.

```
new_list =[list(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(my_list, lambda z: z.startswith('France,)) if not x]
```

**another answer**

in addition to the answer given by Titouan L, I also found the answer using more_itertools

```
import more_itertools as miter
print(list(miter.split_before(my_list, lambda x: x.startswith("France,"))))
```

Comment: What if the first string in the list has no France?

Comment: well, unfortunately the first string in the list has that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a solution with nested loops, as I'm not very experienced with list comprehension and lambda expression.

```py
my_list = ['France, the weather is nice', 'the house is beautiful', 'we have a fresh start here', 'France, the dinner is amazing',
           'the lady is lovely', 'France, the house is beautiful', 'the location is fascinating']

new_list = []
sub_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if i.startswith('France,'):
        if sub_list != []:
            new_list.append(sub_list)
            sub_list=[]

    sub_list.append(i)
new_list.append(sub_list)
```

Comment: Good answer, the only thing is that the question says that you should split if `France` is in the string at all, not just at the start, so you should use `if 'France' in i`

Comment: Even though the questions also uses `.startswith()` ;)

Comment: You are right, I even added the comma. I based my answer on the code sample from the author, and feel like it could have solve his problem, but it does not perfectly fit the question. Note that using `if 'France' in i` would still split the list at the beginning of the string and not before the string `France`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, using recursion:

```
my_list = ['France, the weather is nice', 'the house is beautiful', 'we have a fresh start here', 'France, the dinner is amazing', 'the lady is lovely', 'France, the house is beautiful','the location is fascinating']


def split_list(index=len(my_list) - 1):
    if index < 0:
        return []
    if not my_list[index].startswith('France,'):
        data = split_list(index - 1)
        data[-1].append(my_list[index])
        return data
    else:
        return split_list(index - 1) + [[my_list[index]]]


print(split_list())
```

**Output:**

```
[['France, the weather is nice', 'the house is beautiful', 'we have a fresh start here'], ['France, the dinner is amazing', 'the lady is lovely'], ['France, the house is beautiful', 'the location is fascinating', 'the location is fascinating']]
```

Definitely not the most efficient :)